# auto-refresh (gulp+livereload+jasmine)

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, gulp, livereload, gulp-watch

I'm trying to creat a gulp task to run a test and automatically refresh when changes occur in any .js test file.

This is the code:

```
gulp.task('watch-test', function() {
  // start live-reload server
  plugins.livereload.listen({ start: true});

  var filesForTest = [ 'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',

    'src/app/blocks/testController.module.js',
    'src/app/blocks/testController.js',
    'src/test/spec/sillyControllerSpec.js']

  return gulp.src(filesForTest)
    .pipe(watch(filesForTest))
    .pipe(plugins.jasmineBrowser.specRunner())
    .pipe(plugins.jasmineBrowser.server({port: 8888}))
    .pipe(plugins.livereload());
});
```

It watches the files, but I have to refresh manually the page at the browser.

Any idea what can I do?

Comment: Did you find any solutions on this one?

Answer (score 0):

I found this package that incluide jasmine + livereload

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jasmine-livereload-task